# get URL of webview when URL changes

Tags: android, webview

i use webview to make paypal payment on my android. payment is actually happening at server, i just upload the url into my webview. when payment is complete i redirect browser to a page. this is working fine. but what i want is when page is redirected to this success page i should be able to start new activity. i am using below method but it is not able to get success URL.

```
_webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
            {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
                {
                    //Our servlet only uses one url for both success or failure
                    if (url.trim().equals("http://www.MyDomain.com/MobilePaypal/ReturnPage.aspx")) 
                    { 
                         Intent iPrintReciept = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrintReciept.class) ;
                        //Intent iPrintReciept = new Intent(Payment.this,PrintReciept.class);
                        startActivity(iPrintReciept);

                    } 
                    return false; 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your working class is an activity then use like below

```
Intent iPrintReciept = new Intent(yourActivityName.this, PrintReciept.class);
```

If your working class is not activity the use

```
Intent iPrintReciept = new Intent(context,PrintReciept.class);
```

Comment: jainal thanx for reply the problem does not stay with activity. the problem is when webview loads url i want to track the url's so that when http://www.MyDomain.com/MobilePaypal/ReturnPage.aspx is loaded i can start above activity